# Use fabric to excute code on a remote server from within python

Tags: python, fabric

I would like to call "run()" or "sudo()" with fabric to execute a script on a remote host.
However, I want to do this from within python, and not from the command line:

so instead of:

```
fab.py:
def do_something():
    print "doing something"
    sudo("my_shell_commandline_to_do_something")
```

and then:

```
fab do_something
```

I want to just call do_something from some other python program.
How do I do this? How do I supply the remote host IP address, since tehre is no fabricrc file from within python (or is there?)

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind,
I found it myself :)

its:

```
from fabric.operations import sudo
from fabric.context_managers import settings

with (settings(host_string=remote_ip_address, 
user='myuser', 
key_filename='/tmp/.ssh/myKey.pem')):
    sudo('touch a.txt')
```